# Get Image from limeLine Twitter Fabrc

Tags: android, image, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am in the process of writing a mobile app which makes use of the Twitter/Fabric SDK  and I got a problem. How can i get the image from my home timeline and open this image in another activity? Please help..

```
public class TweetsActivity extends ListActivity {
private TweetViewAdapter adapter;
private Button twSentTweet;
private Button twLogoutButton;
private StatusesService service;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    adapter = new TweetViewAdapter(this);
    service = Twitter.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();

    twSentTweet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.twSendTweet);
    twLogoutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.twLogout);
    twSentTweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            publishTweet();
        }
    });

    twLogoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
            finish();
        }
    });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    loadTweets();
}

public void loadTweets() {
    service.homeTimeline(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
                    adapter.setTweets(result.data);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException error) {
                    Toast.makeText(TweetsActivity.this, "Failed to retrieve timeline",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_feed, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void publishTweet() {
    service = Twitter.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();
    service.update("Привет хабр!", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> tweetResult) {
            Toast.makeText(TweetsActivity.this, "Успешно опубликовали статус",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Toast.makeText(TweetsActivity.this, "Ошибка при отправке твита",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```